# Optimizing Partitioning Data in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading in a bunch of logs that look something like this:

```
id type amt
 0    A 100
 1    B 200
 2    A 100
 3    A 300
 4    B 100
 5    A 100
 6    C 200
 7    C 100
 8    A 200
```

I want to partition this data by type, so each of types A, B, and C would each be on their own machine. The problem is that the partitioning step is too slow for my size of data. The data comes to me in row format, so I'm reading in each row, and parsing it to get the types and such. Is there any way to speed up the extraction and partitioning by doing the partitioning on the fly as part of the parsing step? Just looking for ideas on how to speed it up if all I want to do is extract the data, and write it to disk partitioned. I'm using scala.

Comment: did you get any solution for this ? if so you can explain in your own answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if could help if you share the code to know how you're doing it
the simplest way to write the file partitionned by a field, change your input to dataset and then :

```
result.repartition($"type").write.save(/.../path)
```

if you want to put in a hive table with partitionned column , try :

```
result.repartition($"type").partitionBy("type").write.save(/.../path_to_table)
```

it will give a path like /user/hive/warehouse/table_name/type=A/part-***